# How to Export Variables with a Dynamic Names

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, atomic-design

I have a components folder in nuxt.js

```
/components/atoms/
```

and inside that folder I have an `index.js` to export all components dynamically

```
const req = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/)

const components = {}

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  components[componentName] = req(fileName).default
})

export const { ButtonStyled, TextLead, InputSearch } = components
```

so I can import perfectly as I wish

```
import { ButtonStyled } from "@/components/atoms"
```

the problem is that I am defining the variables to be exported statically, fixed, so for each created component I would need to add another variable manually

I need to dynamically export the variable name

Example:

```
DynamicCreation = ['ButtonStyled', 'TextLead', 'InputSearch']

export const { DynamicCreation } = components 

// output -> export const { ButtonStyled, TextLead,InputSearch  } = components
```

I need to export the name of already unstructured variables

Note: I can not use this `export default components` because I can not import like this `import { ButtonStyled } from "@/components/atoms"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a library that does this type of export, anyone who wants can install via `npm`

I created a Webpack Plugin that makes named exports from a component, maybe this helps other people

### [Weback Plugin - named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
export default components
```

Then in your file where you want to use the components:

```
import * as components from '@/components/atoms'
```

Then when you need to use the components in your Vue files, you need to map them:

```
@Component({
  components: {
    ButtonStyled: components.ButtonStyled
  }
})
```

And now you have:

```
<ButtonStyled></ButtonStyled>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this way, check if is what do you need.

Create a file to import a conjunct of components: allComponents.js

```
export default {
 componentOne: require('./passToOneComponent.js');
 componentTwo: require('./passToOneComponent.js');
 componentThree: require('./passToOneComponent.js');
}
```

After in index.js export the allComponents.js with the name that you wish:

```
export {default as SomeName } from 'allComponents.js';
```

So in the final file, you can make something like:

```
import { SomeName } from 'index.js';

SomeName.componentOne();
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the description of my question, i need import dynamically, not static